# Android ListView scrolling

Tags: android, listview, snapping

I have an Android ListView with very tall rows and it like a vertical gallery of pictures.  When I fling the view I would like it to precisely stop at the start of each view.  Currently it will go over the next view and stop betwen 2 views which is not the effect I want.

Is there a setting that I can use to make this happens?

Comment: There is another Stack overflow post here: [Snap to with a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432261/list-view-snap-to-item)
This should hopefully give you enough of a starting point although this post is so old, you may not care.

Comment: Andrew, Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y) will snap a list to position, selecting the element at position y and snapping the list to where the top of the selected element is y pixels from the top. Would that provide what you need?

I haven't tested it, but it seems that this combined with onScrollStateChanged or AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener would give you a scrolling, snapping ListView.

I hope that's of some use.